# I want to put a pointer to an object that is const into a container that holds non-const pointers. What are my options?

Tags: c++, constants

I have some code that looks like this:

```
void addPtrs(vector<Thing*> & ThingPtrs, const vector<Thing> & actualThings) {
       for (const Thing & t : actualThings)
           if (/*some condition*/)
               ThingPtrs.push_back(&t);
}
```

Basically, I want to modify `ThingPtrs` by giving it pointers to `Thing`s that have some condition. However, because I do not want to modify the actual `Thing`, I labeled `actualThings` as `const`, and now I can't assign a `const` pointer to a non`const` pointer.

Obviously one solution is to simply not make `actualThings` `const`, but I don't actually intend to modify it. Another solution is using a `const_cast`, but I would like to avoid that if possible too.

What are my options in a situation like this?

Comment: If you never intend to modify any `Thing`, your `ThingPtrs` would be defined as `std::vector<Thing const *>&`. Seeing that it stores non-`const` pointers, it implies that some modification _will_ be required at some point, so you don't want any `const`ness.

Comment: I intend to modify `Thing`s, but only through `actualThings` isntead of `ThingPtrs`. Could I define `ThingPtrs` to be of type `vector<const Thing*>`?

Comment: @Dillydill123 Yes, if you change `ThingPtrs` to be `vector<const Thing*>` then your function should compile fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, `const std::vector` will not allow you to modify it's elements directly. Since `actualThings` is const you cannot modify it's content. Any reference or pointer to it's elements will be const.

Any solution you find without changing the function's prototype will ultimately involve converting a `const Thing &` or `const Thing *` to it's non-const equivalent, regardless of how you dress it. Any pointer cast or reinterpretation would just be a round-about `const_cast`.

If you are concerned that `addPtrs` does not modify `actualThings` (in the sense of calling it's non-const member) you could change your interface to accept a begin/end pair of iterators. Other changes that will allow your function to compile include removing const from `actualThings` to get `vector<Thing> & actualThings` or adding const to the type of elements in `ThingPtrs` to get `vector<const Thing*> & ThingPtrs`

Comment: So I tried `vector<const Thing*>` and I'm surprised this compiled. How is this allowed, given that when a `vector` reaches capacity, it has to remake the its container? I also noticed that `vector<Thing * const>` doesn't compile.

Comment: @Dillydill123 This approach does not protect against invalidation. It will indeed break if/when `actualThings` resizes. All pointers and references to elements, along with all iterators are invalidated when that happens. A const pointer **does not guarantee that the pointed object can't change**, only that you can't change it using the pointer. For your other question, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const) for more information on the different places you can put const on a pointer type.

Comment: @Dillydill123 for your 2nd question in comment, just to make sure, you know the difference between `const X*`/ `X const *` vs `X * const` right? (pointer to const X vs const pointer to X)

Comment: Yup I do! I believe I understand why we can't have `vector<int * const>` Correct me if I am wrong, but it doesn't compile because a const pointer would need to be initialized when it is created, which won't be the case if it lives inside the vector. Now this gives me yet another question! Could we do map<int, int * const>? It seems like that should work!

Comment: @Dillydill123 `int * const` is a pointer to a mutable (non-const) `int` and it can't be assigned to a new address once initialized. It still has the same problem as `vector<int*>` where you can't assign a `const int *` to it. It also has a new issue because [std::vector<T>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) requires that `T` be [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable).

Comment: Thanks so much guys, this was incredibly helpful